# How to get a core dump from apache when segfaulting

Tags: httpd, segmentation-fault, dump

I've followed instructions from many locations online on how to get a core dump from apache when it is producing a segfault, but it still refuses to generate the dump.

I have:

1. Added the `CoreDumpDirectory` directive into the `httpd.conf` file and set it to `/tmp`
2. Executed
       `ulimit -c unlimited`
3. Provided the pattern for dumps using
       `echo '/tmp/core-%e.%p' > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`
4. Also ran
       `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid`

Httpd has been restarted, but still no dumps created.

I'm running CentOS 5.8 x64 with `httpd-2.2.3-65.el5.centos.3` and `php-5.3.20-13.el5.art`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does apache have any permission to write to the file you specified in CoreDumpDirectory directive? It should be owned by apache.

Comment: I've set it to /tmp which is publicly writable, but I'll try somewhere else and give it ownership to apache

Comment: Thanks - that did produce a dump, however not in the place I set it! I set the `CoreDumpDirectory` to `/tmp/dumps` and it dumped to `/tmp`... now on with debugging

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer is this:

1. Set up the directive as follow

   `CoreDumpDirectory /tmp/mycoredump`
2. Create the directory:

   `mkdir -p /tmp/mycoredump`
3. Assign ownership to the directory  www-data or httpd

   `chown -R www-data:www-data /tmp/mycoredump`
4. Set permissions to:

   `chmod 777 /tmp/mycoredump`
5. Restart Apache:

   `service apache2 restart`

Comment: Yes, I did just about that, but it ended up dumping into `/tmp` anyway!

Comment: It's never a good idea to `chmod 777` anything

Comment: @sendmoreinfo But what if your use case is making something fully modifiable and executable to the outside world?  ;-)

Comment: You are allowed to shoot yourself in the foot, just don't preach this.

Comment: If I run these, it kills Apache and makes it unable to start... CoreDumpDirectory does not appear to be a valid Apache directive.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you have `PrivateTmp=true` set in your `/usr/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service` (or whatever it's called on your system), meaning Apache actually looks for `/tmp` inside something like `/tmp/systemd-private-c27fc5b152d546159d675e170641529b-apache2.service-IcEt0m/`, Apache won't be able to write to that dir and you won't get cores dumped at all (due to the `systemd` tmp directory having 700 root-only perms).

The solution is to either set `PrivateTmp=false` or modify the permission of the systemd tmp directory after the server starts.

I wasted hours on this to only just now finally realize what the problem was.

Comment: Oh you have no idea how many hours I've wasted on this. Thanks for posting your answer!

Comment: Or don't use a `/tmp` directory at all and store them elsewhere, like `/var/coredumps/`.