# How to create CoreDumpDirectory in AWS?

Tags: httpd.conf, aws-directory-service

I am using AWS but i dont know how to check CoreDumpDirectory exist or not. if not how to create this and which path?? I am trying this but not got any solution [How to get a core dump from apache when segfaulting](https://serverfault.com/questions/470407/how-to-get-a-core-dump-from-apache-when-segfaulting)

Answer (score 1):

As ever the documentation comes to the rescue [CoreDumpDirecrory](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#coredumpdirectory) is an Apache httpd configuration directive which is set within your httpd configuration files .
If you have not configured CoreDumpDirectory then the documentation says it will default to the location of ServerRoot (the details of which can also be found in the documentation).

All I had to do to find this information was enter CoreDumpDirecrory into google search, follow the first link and read the documentation. You should try it.